# Tkinter button.get() returns previous value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I am trying to write a program that returns the value of a selected radio button.

Where is my button creation code:

```
for Ftype in food_type:

if i < 9:
    b = Radiobutton(type_frame, text=Ftype, value=Ftype, variable=selected)
    b.bind("<1>", print_selected)
    b.grid(row=i, sticky=W)
else:
    b = Radiobutton(type_frame, text=Ftype, value=Ftype, variable=selected)
    b.bind("<1>", print_selected)
    b.grid(row=j, column=1, sticky=W)
    j += 1
i += 1
```

i have created the selected variable like this:

```
root = Tk()
selected = StringVar()
```

I have the function for print_selected that looks like this:

```
def print_selected(event):
    print("%s was selected!" % selected.get())
```

It works except it gives me the previous item.  So if I click on item1, then item2, then item3, I would get the following output:

"  was selected!"
"item1 was selected!"
"item2 was selected!"

Any ideas? I have looked and can't find anything similar to what I am asking.

Comment: Use the Radiobutton command argument instead of binding to a mouse click. Or trace the variable. If you show us a [mcve] we can give you a more detailed fix.

Comment: Changing to the command argument worked, but why didn't the bind method work?

Comment: Because your print function is executed first, before the value is changed.

Comment: is there a way to make it so that isn't so?

Comment: Besides the 2 methods I told you? Hmm I suppose you could try binding to the mouse *release*, not sure if that will work. Or you could use a quick function to introduce a delay before your print function is run.